# Group ticks Plotly

Tags: r, plotly, visualization

I have a timeseries of quarterly data from 2000 until today. I would like to create a chart with plotly where I show these data.
I would like to visualize dates in a format such as 2020 Q1.
I am almost able to do so. However, I am not satisfied with the aesthetic of the x-axis when I have the big picture of the chart.

[image]

This is what I have and I do not like much (Image above).

[image]

I like it when I zoom in (Image above)

However, for aesthetic reasons I would prefer to have something like this when I have the big picture:

[image]

```
chart <- plot_ly(x = DatesQ, y = y1, type = 'scatter',  mode = 'lines', name = '', line = list(color = "#003299") ) %>% 
            add_trace(y = y2, type = 'bar', name = '', marker = list(color = "#FFB400" )) %>% 
  add_trace(y = y3, type = 'bar', name = '', marker = list(color = "#FF4B00" )) %>% 
  add_trace(y = y4, type = 'bar', name = '', marker = list(color = "#65B800" )) %>% 
layout(barmode = 'relative', barbase = 0 )
```

This is the vector of Dates that I have used in the 3rd chart

```
> Dates
 [1] "2000-03-31" "2000-06-30" "2000-09-30" "2000-12-31" "2001-03-31" "2001-06-30" "2001-09-30" "2001-12-31" "2002-03-31" "2002-06-30" "2002-09-30" "2002-12-31"
[13] "2003-03-31" "2003-06-30" "2003-09-30" "2003-12-31" "2004-03-31" "2004-06-30" "2004-09-30" "2004-12-31" "2005-03-31" "2005-06-30" "2005-09-30" "2005-12-31"
[25] "2006-03-31" "2006-06-30" "2006-09-30" "2006-12-31" "2007-03-31" "2007-06-30" "2007-09-30" "2007-12-31" "2008-03-31" "2008-06-30" "2008-09-30" "2008-12-31"
[37] "2009-03-31" "2009-06-30" "2009-09-30" "2009-12-31" "2010-03-31" "2010-06-30" "2010-09-30" "2010-12-31" "2011-03-31" "2011-06-30" "2011-09-30" "2011-12-31"
[49] "2012-03-31" "2012-06-30" "2012-09-30" "2012-12-31" "2013-03-31" "2013-06-30" "2013-09-30" "2013-12-31" "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-09-30" "2014-12-31"
[61] "2015-03-31" "2015-06-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-06-30" "2016-09-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-09-30" "2017-12-31"
[73] "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-09-30" "2018-12-31" "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31" "2020-06-30" "2020-09-30" "2020-12-31"
[85] "2021-03-31" "2021-06-30" "2021-09-30" "2021-12-31" "2022-03-31" "2022-06-30"
```

```
DatesQ <-  as.yearqtr(Dates, format = "%Y-%m-%d")
DatesQ <-  rapply(list(DatesQ), as.character)
> DatesQ
 [1] "2000 Q1" "2000 Q2" "2000 Q3" "2000 Q4" "2001 Q1" "2001 Q2" "2001 Q3" "2001 Q4" "2002 Q1" "2002 Q2" "2002 Q3" "2002 Q4" "2003 Q1" "2003 Q2" "2003 Q3" "2003 Q4"
[17] "2004 Q1" "2004 Q2" "2004 Q3" "2004 Q4" "2005 Q1" "2005 Q2" "2005 Q3" "2005 Q4" "2006 Q1" "2006 Q2" "2006 Q3" "2006 Q4" "2007 Q1" "2007 Q2" "2007 Q3" "2007 Q4"
[33] "2008 Q1" "2008 Q2" "2008 Q3" "2008 Q4" "2009 Q1" "2009 Q2" "2009 Q3" "2009 Q4" "2010 Q1" "2010 Q2" "2010 Q3" "2010 Q4" "2011 Q1" "2011 Q2" "2011 Q3" "2011 Q4"
[49] "2012 Q1" "2012 Q2" "2012 Q3" "2012 Q4" "2013 Q1" "2013 Q2" "2013 Q3" "2013 Q4" "2014 Q1" "2014 Q2" "2014 Q3" "2014 Q4" "2015 Q1" "2015 Q2" "2015 Q3" "2015 Q4"
[65] "2016 Q1" "2016 Q2" "2016 Q3" "2016 Q4" "2017 Q1" "2017 Q2" "2017 Q3" "2017 Q4" "2018 Q1" "2018 Q2" "2018 Q3" "2018 Q4" "2019 Q1" "2019 Q2" "2019 Q3" "2019 Q4"
[81] "2020 Q1" "2020 Q2" "2020 Q3" "2020 Q4" "2021 Q1" "2021 Q2" "2021 Q3" "2021 Q4" "2022 Q1" "2022 Q2"
```

This is instead the vector that I am currently using.

To sum up, I would like that in the big picture just few ticks appear while when I zoom in the number of ticks increases (as it usually happens for Dates), and it shows dates in the format as
this "2022 Q2".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When providing data for your questions, it's a far better idea to present that information as the output from `dput` or `reprex`. (You'll find you get answers faster, as well.) You provided the data, regardless of the format. What about the rest of your data? It would be ideal if you shared that, as well.

I answered a question similar to this in the past, but I couldn't find it. However, I did save the code (both the question and my answer).

```
library(plotly)
library(zoo)

set.seed(3958)
d <- tibble::tibble(
  time = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), 
                        as.Date("2020-08-31"), by = "quarters")),
  y = rnorm(seq_along(time)))

d$time <- as.Date(d$time, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

plot_ly(d, x = ~time, y = ~y) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  rangeslider(d$time[10], d$time[19]) %>% 
  layout(xaxis = list(ticktext = paste0(c(rep(2018, 3), 
                                          rep(2019, 4),
                                          rep(2020, 2)),
                                        " Q",
                                        c(2:4, 1)),
                      tickvals = d$time[10:18]))

plot_ly(d, x = ~time, y = ~y) %>%
  add_lines() %>%
  rangeslider(d$time[10], d$time[19]) %>%  
  layout(xaxis = list(
    tickformatstops = list(
      list(dtickrange = list(NULL, "M1"), # every month shown; with year & abbreviated month name
           value = "%Y %b"),
      list(dtickrange = list("M1", "M6"), # from 1 to every 6 months, Year and 'Q' quarter
           value = "%Y Q%q"),
      list(dtickrange = list("M6", NULL), # every 6 months, Year only
           value = "%Y Y")
    )))
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. BTW, by running your code I see no improvement. I will paste a screenshot of it at the end of my original question.